# Android: Uber RideRequestButton Dynamically changing ub_style to white

Tags: android, uber-api

I am looking to change the Uber style of RideRequestButton provided in Uber Rides SDK programmatically (using Java). I know we can change it using xml as uber:ub_style="white", but how can one do using Java Code? I can't find such thing in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Uber Button does not currently support setting the theme programatically after it has been constructed, however at construction you may use `new RideRequestButton(this, null, 0, R.style.MyUberStyle);` where you define a Style called MyUberStyle that contains the the Uber Style you request. However, I recommend instead using two different layout files that are themed like you want and call `context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_black_uber_button, rootView);`

If these don't meet your needs and you have an additional feature request, please file it on https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/issues

Thanks!